# How to configure Custom Role Provider in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have problem with using my Custom Role Provider.

I`ve made class CustomRoleProvider : RoleProvider and method string [] GetRolesForUsers() is overrided:

```
public override string[] GetRolesForUser(string username)
    {
        string[] s = { "StandardAdmin" };

        return s;
    }
```

My web.config now looks like:

```
<roleManager enabled="true" defaultProvider="AccessRoleProvider" >
  <providers>
    <clear />
    <add name="AccessRoleProvider" type="Formularz.Memberships.AccessRoleProvider" applicationName="/" />
  </providers>
</roleManager>
```

and

```
<location path="Memberships.AdminsListPage.aspx">
<system.web>
  <authorization>
    <allow roles="SuperAdmin"/>
    <deny users="*"/>
  </authorization>
</system.web>
```

I have no idea why i can access AdminsListPage.aspx, so I hope you could give some advice for me.

Thank you in advance, Peter

Comment: Give the contents of AdminsListPage.aspx - is security in place?

Comment: Do you just try to add many roles or something else? If first one it can be done in few lines.

Comment: Are you sure the path to your aspx page is "Memberships.AdminsListPage.aspx" and not "Memberships/AdminsListPage.aspx" ?